# TTTableView hidden after returning to TTTableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, three20

I'm writing an application based off of the Three20 framework, and I seem to be having some trouble...

I'm using the TTTableViewController to load data from an endpoint and display a list of the titles, which can be clicked to present a new UIViewController which contains a UIWebView that shows the URL (gotten from the JSON data). However, when I hit the "Back" button in the UIViewController, the view pops back...but the UIWebView doesn't disappear (it is defined with [autorelease]). It stays on top of where the TTTableView should be.

The code I use in SearchResultViewController to initialize the UIWebView is fairly straightforward:

```
- (void)loadView {
    ....
    // Add the UIWebView
    webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, TT_ROW_HEIGHT + 20, TTApplicationFrame().size.width, TTApplicationFrame().size.height - TT_ROW_HEIGHT - toolbar.frame.size.height)] autorelease];
    // Load the URL
    address = self.productIdentifier;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:address];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:webView];
    ....
}
```

And the SearchResultViewController is pushed equally trivially:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Search Again" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goBack)];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [backButton release];

    SearchResultViewController *srvc = [[SearchResultViewController alloc] init];
    srvc.productIdentifier = [[[(id<SearchResultsModel>)self.model results] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] url];
    srvc.title              = [[[(id<SearchResultsModel>)self.model results] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title]; 
    srvc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:srvc animated: YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out; ridiculously stupid mistake. I added the UIWebView to the whole navigationController instead of the view I needed it in. Duh!